# How I Disable Form Close button Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net

Hello dear i need help i want to disable vb.net form close button and want close from button

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        Form2.Show()
        If Form2.Visible = True Then
            e.Cancel = False
        End If

    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch it off like

```
Me.ControlBox = False
```

and if you want to close something

```
Me.Close()
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: i want to show both button minimize and maximum

Comment: @dolatjan Your application can still be closed at any time with Task Manager.